# Int64 seems too short in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to write the largest int64 value to the command line. I tried using `0x1111111111111111` which is 16 ones, and visual studio says that is int64. I would have assumed that would be int16. What am missing here?

Comment: That format is a hexadecimal number. Each digit is *four* bits, not one.

Comment: You are missing 0xFF...FF, and you also ignore signed/unsigned

Comment: or you can also try Int64.MaxValue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`0x` is the prefix for hexadecimal and not binary literals. This means that the binary representation of your number is `0001000100010001000100010001000100010001000100010001000100010001`

There are unfortunately no binary literals in C#, so you either have to do the calculation yourself (`0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`) or use the `Convert` class, for example:

```
short s = Convert.ToInt16("1111111111111111", 2); // "2" for binary
```

In order to just get the largest *Int64* number, you don't need to perform any calculations of your own, as it is already available for you in this field:

```
Int64.MaxValue
```

Comment: You forgot about two's complement and signed vs. unsigned. Int64.MaxValue is actually `0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`.

Answer (score 3):

The literal `0x1111111111111111` is a hexadecimal number. Each hexadecimal digit can be represented using four bits so with 16 hexadecimal digits you need 4*16 = 64 bits. You probably intended to write the binary number `1111111111111111`. You can convert from a binary literal string to an integer using the following code:

```
Convert.ToInt16("1111111111111111", 2)
```

This will return the desired number (-1).

To get the largest `Int64` you can use `Int64.MaxValue` (`0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`) or if you really want the unsigned value you can use `UInt64.MaxValue` (`0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`).

Answer (score 0):

The largest Int64 value is [Int64.MaxValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64.maxvalue.aspx). To print this in hex, try:

```
Console.WriteLine(Int64.MaxValue.ToString("X"));
```